# Add SWT dependency to POM

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, swt

How do I add SWT dependency to POM in eclipse. I tried this

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.swt</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.swt.cocoa.macosx.x86_64</artifactId>
        <version>4.4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

But it says the dependency couldn't be found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maven central repository contains only version 4.3 ([see](http://search.maven.org/#browse%7C-2050256719)), so you must add repository to the pom file. 
This one should work:

```
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>swt-repo</id>
    <url>https://swt-repo.googlecode.com/svn/repo/</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>
```

Comment: Thanks. This works. But what if I have to use Maven central repository as well. What is teh order for checking the dependecies?

Comment: It doesn't matter which repository will be used for particular dependency. Maven will try to serach in every repository he knows about. By default there are maven central and your local repository (.m2 direcotry inside your home folder). Adding new repository to the pom file is just telling maven to search in additional place for dependencies.